# Где применяется v-show (VUE)?

Tags: vue.js

1. Не могу понять где применяется директива **v-show**.
2. Как часто она используется в разработке ?

Comment: В документауии написанно наооборот, или я что-то не понял ? "Разница в том, что элемент с v-show будет всегда оставаться в DOM, а изменяться будет лишь свойство display в его параметрах CSS."

Comment: `v-show` в отличии от `v-if` не убирает контент из `DOM`, он просто задает `display: none;` блоку. Его можно анимировать.

Comment: Все таки остается в DOM ??

Comment: Да, `v-show` остается в `DOM`. А вот `v-if` убирает элемент из `DOM`. Первый нужен для анимации появления/исчезновения контента, а второй для оптимизации количество элементов.